# Q&A system from corpus in java

Tags: java, system, stanford-nlp, analyzer, corpus

I have a corpus that contains a short story with 5 **"who", "what", "when", "where", "why" questions**. I have used [Stanford NLP API](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml) to separate the story into sentences which then the I get the **lemma** for each word in the sentence giving me the base word. I do the same with the questions. I have the story and the sentences saved in separate files from which I use [WS4J](https://code.google.com/p/ws4j/) to help me determine which sentence from the story can answer each question.

I am using this method that takes 2 Strings (question, and the possible) and compares them to each other and returns a value which its a possible answer to the question or not.

```
    public int compSen(double prob, String sen1, String sen2) {

        int cant = 0;

//        String sen2c = remStopWords(sen2);

        String[] sent1 = getWords(sen1);

        String[] sent2 = getWords(sen2);

        for (int s = 0; s < sent2.length - 1; s++) {
            for (int m = s + 1; m < sent2.length; m++) {

                if (sent2[s] != "" && sent2[s].equals(sent2[m])) {

                    sent2[m] = "";
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < sent1.length; i++) {

            for (int j = 0; j < sent2.length; j++) {

                if (sent2[j] != "") {
                    double res = compWord(sent1[i].trim(), sent2[j].trim());
                    if (res >= prob) {
//                    System.out.println(sent1[i] + " " + sent2[j]);
//                    System.out.println(res);
                        cant++;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        return cant;
    }
```

**My other method which compares the words is like this:**

```
    public double compWord(String word1, String word2) {

        ILexicalDatabase db = new NictWordNet();
        WS4JConfiguration.getInstance().setMFS(true);
        RelatednessCalculator rc = new Path(db);
//        String word1 = "gender";
//        String word2 = "sex";
        List<POS[]> posPairs = rc.getPOSPairs();
        double maxScore = -1D;

        for (POS[] posPair : posPairs) {
            List<Concept> synsets1 = (List<Concept>) db.getAllConcepts(word1, posPair[0].toString());
            List<Concept> synsets2 = (List<Concept>) db.getAllConcepts(word2, posPair[1].toString());

            for (Concept synset1 : synsets1) {
                for (Concept synset2 : synsets2) {
                    Relatedness relatedness = rc.calcRelatednessOfSynset(synset1, synset2);
                    double score = relatedness.getScore();
                    if (score > maxScore) {
                        maxScore = score;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (maxScore == -1D) {
            maxScore = 0.0;
        }

//        System.out.println(word1);
//        System.out.println(word2);
//
//        System.out.println(maxScore);
//        System.out.println("sim('" + word1 + "', '" + word2 + "') =  " + maxScore);
        return maxScore;
    }
```

I was wondering if there is another way to better answer questions from a corpus given a story to analyze, since my method is very basic and I managed to answer almost 1-3 questions out of 20. To me this is really good. Any help, idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are testing for an empty string the wrong way.  For example

```
if (sent2[j] != "") { ...
```

Unless the API you are using *guarantees* to canonicalize the strings it returns, that is unreliable.  Java does not guarantee that all empty strings are the same object as `""`.  The following are reliable ways to test if a string is empty:

```
if ("".equal(sent2[j])) { ... // works even for a null !!!

if (sent2[j].equals("") { ...

if (sent2[j].length() == 0) { ...

if (sent2[j].isEmpty()) { ... // Java 6 onwards
```

---

This may not be what it is causing the program to fail, but it is most likely an error.

Comment: Please edit your question to put the **correct** code into it.  As your question is currently written, my Answer is most likely the correct answer.  If you want answers for a different version of your question, then you should update it.

Comment: Yeah no its not that, It wasnt really a coding error. I was asking for a better way to compare the similarity of a block of text to another. Not just word by word but the meaning of the sentence. Thats why I was using the Standford NLP API. But thanks for you tip.

Comment: So ... fix your Question!   'Cos right now the way that you asked it means that people either don't understand what you are asking, or they give up trying after seeing the clearly bogus example code.  Seriously, the onus is on you to write your questions well ... if you want them to be answered.

Comment: Fix it how? at the bottom of the code I try to explain best I can what Im trying to achieve.

Comment: How?  Well that is up to you.  You are the person who understands what you are trying to ask.  It is your problem to >>express<< that so that other people understand.  (We can't read your mind!)  But I would start by fixing the bogus code.

Comment: Another possibility (and I am not an NLP expert, so I don't know) is that what you are asking is "really basic", and people are not bothering because of that.  Note that a lot of "is there another way" questions can be solved by doing some research / reading.  A third possibility is that few Stanford NLP experts read / answer questions on StackOverflow.

Comment: I dont know what to tell you man, this question is old and its not really helping anybody, and I got it working a long time ago.

Comment: Well you should delete it.  Or write an answer yourself.   In fact, writing the answer yourself is the best / most community minded solution!

Comment: I cant delete it, it wont let me